# Add external javascript to user control... but put the file reference at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to be able to add an external js file for a user control (using

```
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("SuggestionSearch", 
"~/Secure/Shared/SuggestionSearch.js");
```

syntax)

But it puts the javascript file on the page too early... is there a way to put the file at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Have you looked at jquery? http://api.jquery.com/ready/ If you have to use that syntax, I'm not sure there is a way to put the file at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

Something like this could work:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "SuggestionSearch",
String.Format("<script src='{0}' type='text/javascript'></script>", ResolveUrl("~/Secure/Shared/SuggestionSearch.js")));
```